# It is valid to write SELECT 'a' colName in TSQL, what is the alternate in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

If I write `SELECT 'a' colName UNION SELECT 'b' colName` in TSQL, it returns a temporary table form and I can use it later in my stored procedure, as well what is the alternate in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you must always select from a table.

Fortunately, they have provided a table especially for queries like the one you want to write - the dual table.

Your query would therefore become:

```
select 'a' colname from dual union all
select 'b' colname;
```

Note that I've changed the union to a union all, to avoid unnecessary sorts/distincts.

If you're going to be using this in PL/SQL, it very much depends on what you're going to do with the results as to how you would code it.

If you're going to use the results to do some DML, e.g. insert into a table, you'd just do it in a single DML statement, e.g.:

```
begin
  insert into some_table (some_column)
  select 'a' colname from dual union all
  select 'b' colname from dual;
end;
/
```

If you're going to use it to do something that can't be done in a single DML statement, you're going to need to return the values into something. That could be looping through a cursor, or it could be returning into a collection, e.g.:

```
begin
  for rec in (select 'a' colname from dual union all
              select 'b' colname from dual)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('colname = '||rec.colname);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

or

```
declare
  type t_vals is table of varchar2(1);
  v_vals t_vals;
begin
  select colname
  bulk collect into v_vals
  from   (select 'a' colname from dual union all
          select 'b' colname from dual);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

`TSQL` and `Oracle SQL` both are developed based on `SQL`. But they have some differences with each other. One of the key differences that related to your question, is the minimum structure of a `SELECT` statement.

`SQL` says that a `SELECT` statement minimally should be in the following form:

```
SELECT expressions FROM table
```

`Oracle SQL` also defines the same rule for the `SELECT` statement in minimum.

In PL/SQL:

```
SELECT ... [BULK COLLECT] INTO ... FROM table
```

But `TSQL`, changes this rule and says that a `SELECT` statement minimally could be constructed as below:

```
SELECT expressions
```

Finally, in `Oracle SQL` you need to execute a `SELECT` statement against a relation such as Table, but in `TSQL` you can execute a `SELECT` statement without using any relation.(For example: Selecting a constant)

Comment: `PL/SQL` is Oracle's procedural language extension for SQL - if you are just talking about native queries (as you seem to be from your code) then you probably do not mean `PL/SQL` but instead "the SQL dialect used by Oracle" (or some equivalent wording) since in PL/SQL `SELECT expressions FROM table` is not valid as you need to use `SELECT ... [BULK COLLECT] INTO ... FROM table` to put the values from the `SELECT` into a variable and you would need to wrap it in a `DECLARE ... BEGIN ... END;` block.

Comment: @MT0 You are A HUNDRED % TRUE. But you are trying to put an output of a select into a variable, but I do not mean this. I just want to describe the SELECT simple form in pl/sql. refer to here: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/select.php

Comment: That is not an official Oracle documentation and to have "PL/SQL" in the title and body is very misleading/wrong as they are not discussing PL/SQL but just (Oracle's dialect of) SQL. You cannot use the code in that webpage in PL/SQL unless you either (1) add an `INTO`/`BULK COLLECT INTO` clause or (2) put the output into a cursor.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm#i2066378

Comment: That is the Oracle documentation for Oracle's SQL - as I said before, it will not work in PL/SQL without either (1) adding an `INTO`/`BULK COLLECT INTO` clause or (2) putting the output into a cursor. Beyond that, I'm not sure what point you are trying to make by linking to the documentation without any other comment.

Comment: If you want the syntax for PL/SQL's `SELECT` statement then look at the [PL/SQL user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm) rather than the Database SQL reference (since Oracle's SQL is not the same thing as Oracle PL/SQL).

Comment: Do you have any official documentation for this: "since Oracle's SQL is not the same thing as Oracle PL/SQL"? Since your link is for SELECT INTO, which is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176126/discussion-between-vahid-farahmandian-and-mt0).

Comment: Try writing a PL/SQL block `BEGIN SELECT 1 FROM DUAL; END;` ([SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/17b6d/1)) it will raise an exception `PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement`. You need to use `SELECT ... INTO` in PL/SQL; hence I linked to the correct (and not irrelevant) documentation.

Comment: @MT0 Great and thank you for great discussion. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

i think he is just asking how to rewrite

```
SELECT 'a' colName UNION SELECT 'b' colName
```

in pl/sql.
So this is the answer

```
select 'a' colname from dual union all
select 'b' colname from dual ;
```

[Read more](http://asporacle.com/oracle-database/learn-oracle-pl-sql-live-project/)